# Solution for installing web3

Tags: javascript, web3js

I had a lot of trouble installing the web3.js library when following a tutorial. I ran into two issues and I will go over how to fix both just in case someone else needs help and wants to avoid wasting a bunch of time :)

I kept getting an error that said **node-gyp didn't exist**.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing I did was run `npm list -g --depth 0`
`sudo npm list -g --depth 0` This should give you a list of modules that are globally installed. If you don't see node-gyp in there then run `npm i -g node-gyp` . Run the above command again and you should see it! After doing that I followed a list of steps from this link: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1136

Which asks you to do this:

```
sudo su -
npm install -g node-gyp             # Does nothing if it's already installed
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib    # Replace /usr/local/lib with the path from npm list
which node-gyp                      # Should show the path to node-gyp
node-gyp BUILDTYPE=Release rebuild  # Don't need sudo cause you're already in a sudo shell
exit                                # Quit
```

If that doesn't work try this:

`npm i -g node-gyp@latest && npm config set node_gyp "/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib"` (**REPLACE** with your own path that prints when you run npm list)

After doing all that, I had a new error.

> sh: node-gyp-build: command not found

Then I ran:

```
npm i -g node-gyp-build
```

And now I have web3 added as a dependency to my package.json! Happy to help further